New SimplePie Installation Produces "Class not found" Error
I'm trying to upgrade a SimplePie https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie installation on XAMPP; moving from PHP 5.x to 8.2; essentially a brand new installation. It was functioning as expected under the PHP 5.x installation. I'm getting the following error ...

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "SimplePie\SimplePie" not found in
C:\xampp\htdocs\examplesite\php\library\SimplePie\SimplePie.php:26
Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\examplesite\php\autoloader.php(84):
include() #1 [internal function]:
SimplePie_Autoloader->autoload('SimplePie\Simpl...') #2
C:\xampp\htdocs\examplesite\php\library\SimplePie.php(10):
class_exists('SimplePie\Simpl...') #3
C:\xampp\htdocs\examplesite\php\autoloader.php(84):
include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 [internal function]:
SimplePie_Autoloader->autoload('SimplePie') #5
C:\xampp\htdocs\examplesite\php\autoloader.php(50):
class_exists('SimplePie') #6
C:\xampp\htdocs\examplesite\rss_demo.php(3):
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #7 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\examplesite\php\library\SimplePie\SimplePie.php on
line 26

... and haven't been able to fix this. Any guidance / thoughts much appreciated. Thank you.
Edit: Manual installation.

I solved this by installing SimplePie with Composer :)
